# How to make a view scroll against a scrollview animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview

So I have a UIView and I want to have it animate a translation in the opposite direction of the scrollviews scroll animation. How would I go about doing this? Of course this should be depend on the `scrollview.contentOffset` I think anyway. So if you scroll the other way it goes back to it's place. So the translation is dependent on how far the user scrolls. I am trying to use the following code. Also note that the UIView I currently do not have as a child of the scrollview. It is suppose to stay on screen at all time, but change positions.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= scrollView.contentSize.width {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's not a child of the scrollview, doesn't it just stay in place automatically?

Comment: yes it does. I don't have a problem with that sorry if my wording was misleading that was just a side not incase that would change the situation in anyway trying to make it animate at the same rate as the scroll.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you want the view to go right across the screen?  What should it do when it gets to the right edge?

Comment: So the idea is that it moves to the right, but a bit at a time. I have paging enabled on my scroll view so it acts very similarly to the UIPageViewController, but for every page the view would translate a bit more. So it always stays on screen and it doesn't ever completely get to the edge. So say you are on page one of the scroll view, and swipe back it would go to it's previous position. It always goes in the opposite direction of which you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let percentage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.contentSize.width
    self.box.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * percentage
}
```

Just calculate the percentage of the contentSize that you have scrolled and set the X position to the same percentage of the screen width.

It could do with some improvements to make sure the view doesn't go beyond the bounds of the screen in certain conditions. So you may need to factor in the width of the box in the calculations as an enhancement.

Here is the code I used for testing, The background image is a 4K wallpaper image.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var box = UIView()
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true


        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "background")
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

        box.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 110, width: 100, height: 100)
        box.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(box)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let percentage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.contentSize.width
        let xPosition = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * percentage

        self.box.frame.origin.x = xPosition
    }
}
```

Comment: hey so how would I go about doing this if say I wanted the view to stop at certain points? Right now I have the x coordinate set to 15, but when I use your solution it of course resets it to 0 when I start scrolling. I have tried using self.box.frame.origin.x += xPosition, but that doesn't quite do what I want it to.

Comment: That doesn't quite do what I want it to at least like this it will start at the position initially set. However, I want it to stop at another predefined spot when the scroll for that page is complete say x = 40.